# Conditional assignment using delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

I want to assign to a datatable such that.

If datatable is null create a new datatable else clear datatable

The code I have written

```
datatable= (datatable== null) ? 
   new DataTable() :  
  delegate(){datatable.Clear(); return datatable;});
```

How this will be possible using delegates or anonymous methods? Using shortest code possible.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question but remember, the shortest code isn't always the best code.  In this scenario you might be better to use a normal if statement so your code is more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: I am just learning delegates.And was wondering is this possible through delegates!(just for learning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you *could* use delegates, but I really wouldn't. I'd just use:

```
if (dataTable == null)
{
    dataTable = new DataTable();
}
else
{
    dataTable.Clear();
}
```

That's a *lot* clearer in terms of what it's doing, IMO.

Here's the delegate version in all its hideousness:

```
dataTable = dataTable == null ? new DataTable() :
    ((Func<DataTable>)(() => { dataTable.Clear(); return dataTable; }))();
```

Comment: @Zain: I have *no* idea what that comment means. EDIT: Okay, now I've compiled it for myself... that's *not* an exception, it's a compile-time error. It's it's method name **expected**, not **excepted**. Huge difference. I've fixed it now - more brackets were needed...

Comment: I assume "excepted" is "expected" but still don't know what you mean @Zain

Comment: @Smudge202: It means he tried to compile my code, and it didn't compile. He could have been significantly clearer though...

Comment: Will you please explain  last 2 braces () in your code what are they doing?

Comment: I can Zain, but probably won't come out well in a comment.  The _false_ part of the tenary operator is a delegate... Func<DataTable>.  If you don't add the final two bracers then what you are returning is a delegate.  A delegate won't cast to a datatable, what you need is the result of the delegate.  By adding the bracers you're telling the compiler to execute the delegate, which in turn returns a datatable.

Comment: @Zain: They're *executing* the delegate. The type of the conditional expression is just `DataTable`, so given a `Func<DataTable>`, we need to execute it to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this maybe?

```
Func<DataTable, DataTable> datatable = (n => {
    if (n == null)
        n = new DataTable();
    else
        n.Clear();
    return n; });
```